# Ending a conversation with someone you don't want to talk to

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, idiom-request

Is there an expression/word for to get someone to stop talking by lying to them or an excuse or otherwise cunning ways so that you end the conversation with them? As in the contexts below,

> John starts talking to Mary, and begs for money; but Mary [requested expression] him, telling him that she's donated all of her money to a charity.
>
> Sarah starts a conversation with Adam, but Adam doesn't like her too much, so he [requested expression] her by talking in the shortest way possible.

Comment: Like giving someone the cold-shoulder?

Answer (score 1):

Cut the conversation short

He 'cut the conversation short' or 'brought it to a close' or 'concluded it swiftly' or 'deftly ended it' - by lying to her.

Answer (score 0):

"Dismissed" should work fine if that's the point your trying to convey.